# capturing durations (intervals) between tracepoints in perf

Tags: linux, performance, monitoring, dtrace

When using the `perf` tool (Linux), is there any simple and convenient way to time durations between two tracepoints?

The obvious use is for syscall `sys_enter` and `sys_exit` points like `sys_enter_fsync` and `sys_enter_fsync`. But I'm also interested in both dynamic and [statically defined](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Static-Probe-Points.html) tracepoints as supported by `perf probe`. Think "duration between PostgreSQL's `transaction__start` and either `transaction__commit` or `transaction__abort`".

Ideally a way to use the info in `perf timechart` and/or aggregate it in `perf stat`.

Is the only option to use tools like DTrace or SystemTap? Or ebpf maybe? Or am I missing something in `perf`'s docs? How to time between two tracepoints, report durations, etc?